# Inserir string na primeira Coluna

Tags: linux, regex, shell-script, awk, sed

Estou quebrando a cabeça com uma coisa muito simples, preciso inserir um ";" (ponto e virgula) após um sort/uniq em um arquivo. Como retorna a quantidade das linhas repetidas, preciso que este retorno que é sempre na primeira coluna seja inserida este ";". Já pesquisei com "CUT, AWK, SED" e não cheguei em um resultado satisfatório.

Exemplo:

```
cat /tmp/filtrado2.txt|  sort| uniq -c| sort -nr
```

Grato em puder me ajudar.

Comment: O que seria este sort/uniq, uma string ?

Comment: O Sort/Uniq é o comando que eu setei. Fiz um Sort e depois o Uniq, conforme o exemplo que citei acima. Após o resultado por eles, que é gerado na primeira coluna, queria inserir o ";" nele.

Comment: Tem como postar o conteúdo do seu arquivo ?

Comment: Sim, antes de "Mar" tem o valor 1 que é o retorno do Sort + Uniq, e a string ";" deveria vir logo após este valor. Lembrando, o padrão é apenas a coluna, pois este valor 1 nem sempre se repete, pode ser 1000, 45678, 2, e etc.

Comment: 1 Mar  3 00:01; 113.78.57.53;  unknown;  <alonso4t@xxxx>;  BS TOYS AND SAMBA TOYS - 3D FILES

Comment: Um arquivo de entrada e outra de saída desejada ajuda. Provavelmente pode ser feito sem o uso de qualquer outra coisa que awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você usar uma expressão regular no sed para selecionar qualquer número: `[0-9]+`

Além disto, usar o operador `&` que recupera o texto que casou com a expressão de busca.

Ficaria assim:

```
cat /tmp/filtrado2.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed -r 's/[0-9]+/&;/'
```

Comment: Boa isso mesmo. Funcionou. Uma duvida, ele pega qualquer numero e insere o ";". Como que ele sabe que é apenas os números da primeira coluna, pois tem números em outros locais do texto e ele não insere este ";".

Comment: O que vai determinar isto é a expressão regular usada no sed. O '&' "guarda" o texto que casou com a expressão.  Então, o que o comando acima vai fazer é substituir o texto que casou com a expressão pelo próprio texto, mais o conjunto de caracteres que você colocar ao lado do '&'.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
cat /tmp/filtrado2.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/1/1;/'
```

Comment: Ele adicionou o ";" no final da linha e não na coluna onde contém o valor 1

Comment: Você quer que substitua o 1 por ; ou que insira o ; onde contém o 1? Eu posso ter me confundindo.

Comment: Gostaria de acrescentar o ";" após o 1, ficando : "1;"

Comment: Editei o comando, teste novamente.

Comment: Olá Douglas, na verdade, desta forma eu já tinha conseguido, o problema é que não existe um padrão exato. O valor 1 foi apenas um exemplo, mas esta primeira coluna pode ter desde o valor 1 a 1 milhão, por isso precisava de algo que utilizasse como padrão a primeira coluna e não o valor dela.

Comment: Verdade, vou pensar em algo melhor.